# vba find text and export

Tags: vba, powerpoint

```
Sub FindWordCopySentence() 
  Dim appExcel As Object 
  Dim objSheet As Object 
  Dim aRange As Range 
  Dim intRowCount As Integer 
  intRowCount = 1 
  Set aRange = ActiveDocument.Range 
  With aRange.Find 
    Do 
      .Text = "shall" ' the word I am looking for
      .Execute 
      If .Found Then 
        aRange.Expand Unit:=wdSentence 
        aRange.Copy 
        aRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd 
        If objSheet Is Nothing Then 
          Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
          'Change the file path to match the location of your test.xls
          Set objSheet = appExcel.workbooks.Open("C:\temp\test.xls").Sheets("Sheet1") 
          intRowCount = 1 
        End If 
        objSheet.Cells(intRowCount, 1).Select 
        objSheet.Paste 
        intRowCount = intRowCount + 1 
      End If 
    Loop While .Found 
  End With 
  If Not objSheet Is Nothing Then 
    appExcel.workbooks(1).Close True 
    appExcel.Quit 
    Set objSheet = Nothing 
    Set appExcel = Nothing 
  End If 
  Set aRange = Nothing 
End Sub
```

I am unable to run this code on PPT using VBA! As I try to debug it throws an error saying the Arange line is In correct.

Comment: Try deleting the a in arange ... range. nm ... code is illegible in this format

Comment: That didn't work my friend . I already tried that. Can someone please help me to use extend class in PowerPoint vba . I would like to copy a sentence if a particular word is detected

Answer (score 0):

the error is generated because the "range" variable type don't exist in powerpoint. If you try to call a excel range yo must to do this:

1. go to tools=>references ,and select the Microsoft excel X.XX object library. (x.xx respond to the excel versión you have installed)
2. writes :

   Dim aRange As Excel.Range

instead of:

```
Dim aRange As Range
```

When you need to interact with other programs in VBA, remember first assign it to references.

I hope that this help you.

Humberto

Comment: I need to do that in PowerPoint ! Actually I am trying to copy a complte sentence in PowerPoint if a certain word occurrs . What I could not get it extend the selection and copy the whole sentence.